# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, xstream

I am using Xstream in my code. Below is the initialization part:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver()) {
            protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
                return new MapperWrapper(next) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                    public boolean shouldSerializeMember(Class definedIn,
                            String fieldName) {
                        return definedIn != Object.class ? super
                                .shouldSerializeMember(definedIn, fieldName)
                                : false;
                    }
                };
            };
        };
```

The suprizing thing is that, when I call this part from a temporary main method it goes fine, but once I run my app and thiscode gets called, I get an exception as shown below:

```
12-07 19:17:56.374 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.374 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.375 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.375 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.388 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.389 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.390 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.391 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.391 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.397 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.397 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.403 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.403 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.405 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.405 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.408 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.408 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.410 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.412 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.412 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.414 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.417 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory>
12-07 19:17:56.417 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk, PID: 8957
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver.<init>(JettisonMappedXmlDriver.java:77)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver.<init>(JettisonMappedXmlDriver.java:63)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver.<init>(JettisonMappedXmlDriver.java:55)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk.transaction.TransactionPayloadProcessorImpl.processTransactionPayload(TransactionPayloadProcessorImpl.java:20)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4786)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19902)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
12-07 19:17:56.418 8957-8957/com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Below is my build.gradle. As can be seen I have added a jettison jar in my libs folder as that wasn't available in the xstream classes.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
mavenCentral()

maven {
    url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'
}
}


android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
        }
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rsa.mobile.android.transactionsigningsdk"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
        exclude module: 'xmlpull'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile ('com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'xmlpull'
    }
    compile files ('libs/jettison-1.3.jar')
    compile files ('libs/commons-codec-1.7.jar')
}
```

Can someone please help out.

Comment: I found no solution to this and ended up using Gson, which solved the purpose.